# Batch script to check last reboot time with if else condition

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I want to get few details from my server like the last reboot time using a batch file.
I am using the command

systeminfo | findstr "Time:"

to get the current up time of the server

now my issue is I want to compare the current up time against the computer date and time and ensure that it shows "Success" if it rebooted less than 15 days else "Alert" if not rebooted in less than 15 days

Comment: The timestamp of the hidden *.SYS files in the root of the system drive are when it was last rebooted, too.  You could use them with FORFILES.EXE to check for age.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to convert a `MM/DD/YYYY` date format to a Julian Date.  If you do that, you can subtract `now` from `boot` to find the `difference`.

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php

Adapting the `Date2JDate` formula, I was able to get the date the server booted, and today's date; and calculate the elapsed days:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%i in ('net statistics server ^| find /i "Statistics since"') do set _boot=%%i
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%i in ('date /t') do set _now=%%i

call :Date2JDate %_boot% _bootJD
call :Date2JDate %_now% _nowJD

set /a _Elapsed=%_nowJD%-%_bootJD%

if %_Elapsed% LSS 15 (echo Success) else (echo Alert)
ENDLOCAL

goto TheEnd

:Date2JDate
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%i in ('echo %1') do (set mm=%%i&set dd=%%j&set yy=%%k)
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
ENDLOCAL & SET %~2=%JD%
goto TheEnd

:TheEnd
```

Of course this assumes that the date format of the server is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Comment: My coding is

@ echo off
del "C:\temp\%computername%.txt
echo.>>C:\temp\%computername%.txt
echo date=%date%>>C:\temp\%computername%.txt 
echo time=%time%>>C:\temp\%computername%.txt
echo hostname =systeminfo | findstr "Domain Name:">>C:\temp\%computername%.txt
ipconfig | findstr "IP Address">>C:\temp\%computername%.txt
systeminfo | findstr "Time:">>C:\temp\%computername%.txt
@ echo off

This will capture the date and time ,host name and also the last boot record and save it on txt file and I need to compare the system time vs last boot time and alert me if reboot is less than 15 days.

Comment: I modified my code to make it work for you. Just save it as CheckBoot.bat and add this line to your code: `call CheckBoot>>C:\temp\%computername%.txt`. If you want some text with the status (Success/Alert), just add the text to the `echo` statements in the `CheckBoot.bat` file.